# How can I insert data (event) into Google Calendar with PHP?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I am trying to insert events into Google Calendar, but I get errors everytime. I've been searching for hours to get answer, but I found nothing for my problem. I tested a lot of examples, without success. I'm new in Google Calendar, and I can't really understand the google api documentation.

I have a Fullcalendar which uses the Google Calendar (Gcal) as backend. I can read data from Gcal without any problems.  When I try to displayed using Fullcalendar, but when I want to write some test datas into Gcal it gives me errors. I want to make a Calendar application which serves as a reservation app. So I have a Calendar, which is displayed to everyone who enter the page, and they can reserve appointments, which are stored in my Google Calendar.

The main is problem is that, I don't really know how to make the connection to Google Calendar for writing data. Every sample I've seen, solves the problem different way, major of them are outdated, some of them uses Sessions, but I don't need Session because the Calendar I want to display is FIX, everyone sees the same.

**The code:**

```
require_once 'Google/src/Google/autoload.php';
require_once "Google/src/Google/Client.php";
require_once "Google/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php";

$client_id = 'XXXXXXXXXX-f9ltk86b2klat20k1osmfbgpu4u1vqse.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // Server Key
$email_address = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX-f9ltk86b2klat20k1osmfbgpu4u1vqse@developer.gserviceaccount.com';


$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Calendar");
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setDeveloperKey($key);

$client->setScopes(array(
 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 
));

$cal = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
$event->setSummary('Title');
$event->setDescription('Title');
$event->setLocation('Somewhere');
$start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2013-08-17T16:00:00.000-07:00');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2013-08-17T17:00:00.000-07:00');
$event->setEnd($end);
$createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('<Calendar ID>', $event);
```

**The exception it generates:**

> [19-Jun-2015 09:08:59 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/hpba8d7p1f6l65ruhbl9qigvks%40group.calendar.google.com/events?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:
>   (401) Login Required' in
>   /var/www/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/calendar/Google/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Login Required` means that you have not authenticated properly.

By looking at the scope you are using I think that might give you a hint as to why its not working

> 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'

You are passing the scope for Google+ you should be passing one of the Google calendars [scopes](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth) if you want to access Google calendar data.

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar    read/write access to Calendars
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly read-only access to Calendars

**Authenticate with a service account**

```
<?php
 require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
   session_start();     
/************************************************   
 The following 3 values an befound in the setting   
 for the application you created on Google      
 Developers console.         Developers console.
 The Key file should be placed in a location     
 that is not accessable from the web. outside of 
 web root.   

 In order to access your GA account you must    
 Add the Email address as a user at the     
 ACCOUNT Level in the GA admin.         
 ************************************************/
$client_id = '[your client]';
    $Email_address = '[your service account email]';     
    $key_file_location = '[Your key]';      

    $client = new Google_Client();      
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);    

// separate additional scopes with a comma   
$scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";    
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(    
    $Email_address,      
    array($scopes),     
    $key         
    );      
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {        
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);       
}       
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);    

?>
```

code ripped from tutorial [PHP Google Calendar service account](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-with-php-service-account/)

**Tip**: make sure that you have given the service account access to the calendar in question.  You just need to add the service account email to the calendar like you would any other user.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, I edited my code with the info provided by you, but it gives me the following exception: 

[19-Jun-2015 10:10:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Unable to parse the p12 file.  Is this a .p12 file?  Is the password correct?  OpenSSL error: error:0D06B08E:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_READ_BIO:not enough data' in /var/www/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/calendar/Google/src/Google/Signer/P12.php:55

The problem is that, I copied my Server Api Key into the $key variable, I didn't use any Key File, because I can't find it.

Comment: you have to use the key file that's how you get access, just removing it isn't going to help you.  If you are out of gas in your car can you just drive with out getting more gas?   Go to Google developer console and create a key.

Comment: I have created 2 keys, 1 for server applications, 1 for browser applications. As i mentioned before, I copied the Server Api Key to the Key variable: 

$key="<My Server Api Key>";

I don't see any Download Key option at [link]console.developers.google.com[link], they might removed it, or I just can't find it. I keep searching the google, how can I download the key file, but I think it has been disabled, they are providing only the Api key.

Comment: I had to create a new ClientID - Service Account, this is how I could get the key file.

Comment: Now: `[19-Jun-2015 11:02:58 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/hpba8d7p1f6l65ruhbl9qigvks%40gr‌​oup.calendar.google.com/events: (403) Forbidden' in /var/www/XXXXXXXXXXX/calendar/Google/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110`. In the Google console -> Permissions my service account's permission is set to Owner, the calendar I'm trying to edit is shared to public, and the email account is added, with write permission.

Comment: Now its working finally, I forgot to add my Service Account Email to my Calendar. Thanks for help, you are amazing! :)